# Buttons in the cell are not hidden when the section of uitableview is collapsed

Tags: swift, button, cell

I am implementing a `UITableView` with sections and collapsible headers. The cells of the section have labels and buttons. The labels are collapsed, but the buttons remain idle (not hidden) when I collapse the header.

I need an implementation where the buttons appears when the cell is expanded and is hidden when the cell is collapsed. I have used a custom cell that has the button inside a stack view. In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbPFQ.png) the arrow represents the table section header view, and the radio buttons have to be hidden after collapsing.

Here is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (sections[indexPath.section].expanded)
        {
            return 244
        }
        else
        {

            return 0
        }
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = ExpandableDashboardView()
        print("title\(sections[section].title)")
        header.customInit(title: sections[section].title, section: section, delegate: self,isOpen:sections[section].expanded)
        return header

    }

    func toggleSection(header: ExpandableDashboardView, section: Int) {
        sections[section].expanded = !sections[section].expanded

        settingsTable.beginUpdates()
        if sections[section].expanded == true
        {

            header.changeInit(title: sections[section].title, section: section, delegate: self)
        }
        else
        {
            header.customInit(title: sections[section].title, section: section, delegate: self, isOpen: sections[section].expanded)


        }

class ExpandableDashboardView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView{
    var delegate : ExpandableDashboardDelegate!
    var section:Int!
    var image = UIImage()

    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:#selector(selectDashboardHeader)))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func customInit(title:String,section:Int,delegate:ExpandableDashboardDelegate,isOpen:Bool)
    {
//        if isOpen == true{
////            self.textLabel?.text = "\u{25B6} \(title)"
//            self.textLabel?.text = "\u{25BC} \(title)"
//        }
//        else{
//            self.textLabel?.text = "\u{25BC} \(title)"
//        }
//        self.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black

        self.textLabel?.text = "\u{25B6} \(title)"                  //02C3
        self.section = section
        self.delegate = delegate
        layoutSubviews()

    }

    func changeInit(title:String,section:Int,delegate:ExpandableDashboardDelegate)
    {
        self.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black

        self.textLabel?.text = "\u{25BC} \(title)"
        self.section = section
        self.delegate = delegate
        layoutSubviews()
    }

    func selectDashboardHeader(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer)
    {
        let cell = gestureRecognizer.view as! ExpandableDashboardView
        delegate.toggleSection(header: self , section: cell.section)
        print("section\(cell.section)")
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 17.0/255.0, green: 83.0/255.0, blue: 168.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to help without any code, try adding some [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: i have attached it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue behind. check the "clip to bounds" in the interface builder for the buttons. This will make the buttons to hide.